# Android Text size same on phone and tablets both high density

Tags: android, text, size, resolution

I have successfully developed my Android application to look good across different device size.
I detected the widths with code such as:

```
if((this.deviceWidth > 500) && (this.deviceWidth < 720)){
                this.isLargeDevice = true;
```

I did this for different device sizes but I run into trouble when I have a phone that has a high resolution like a tablet.
The phone displays the settings of an Xlarge Tablet so the text is too big.

I have read the android developer how to's a bunch. 
How should I handle these small device sizes with such high resolutions like tablets have?

thanks

Comment: Ahhh I didn't realize I could upload multiple .APK files. I think I will make one .apk for phones and one .apk for tablets. Each with it's own settings.